# Include/call external class in laravel

Tags: php, class, laravel, external

Even though I have seen multiple questions like this in stackoverflow, I still wasn't able to get my custom php class working in laravel. I have done the following:

laravel -> app -> Libraries -> DateFunction.php     as my filepath

The actual DateFunction.php contains the following code

```
<?php

namespace App\Libraries;

class DateFunction
{
    public $timeWorked;

    public function getRealHours($time) {
        if ($time / 60 < 1) {
             $this->timeWorked = $time . "m";
        } else {
            $hours = $time / 60;
            $minutes = $time % 60;

            $this->timeWorked  = $hours . "h" . $minutes . "m";
        }

        return $this->timeWorked;
    }

}
```

In my controller I have used 
`use App\Libraries\DateFunction;`

But in my View when I use

```
 @foreach ($labourentries as $labour)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $labour->labourtype_id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ getRealHours($labour->minutes_worked)  }}</td>
                </tr>
   @endforeach
```

it still give me the error: Call to undefined function getRealHours()

Any help would be much appreciated. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**When you write `use App\Libraries\DateFunction` only have available the DateFunction class in this controller, and you should use it as follows:**

```
Class AlohaController 
{

    public function something()
    {
        $InstanceClass = new DateFunction;
        $realHour = $InstanceClass->getRealHours(48);
    }
}
```

If you want to use globally getRealHours() You do not need to have a class.

If you want to create a function helper you have to do the following:

1. edit the file `composer.json`putting the path of your helper file

   [image]
2. run `composer dumpautoload` to generate the bootstrap file
3. Helpers file should look like this:

   ```
   function getRealHours($time) {

       $timeWorked = 0;

       if ($time / 60 < 1) {
           $timeWorked = $time . "m";
       } else {
           $hours = $time / 60;
           $minutes = $time % 60;

           $timeWorked  = $hours . "h" . $minutes . "m";
       }

       return $timeWorked;

   }
   ```

**Another possible solution**

In your controller creates an instance of the DateFunction class and send it to your view.

Your controller should look like this:

```
$helpers = new DateFunction;
return view('path.to.view', ['helpers' => $helpers]);
```

And in your view you could use it in this way:

```
<td>{{ $helpers->getRealHours($labour->minutes_worked)  }}</td>
```

Comment: I included it as a helper file and it worked. thanks a lot. I don't really understand how to do it as a class though. Would you mind to elaborate a little bit? cheers

Comment: If you want to use a class, you could do is create a method in the Model Labour (I assume $labourentries is a collection of some model), this method would use the DateFunction class to make the calculation. doing this, in the view iterate the collection you would use something like this: $labour->minutesWorkedToRealHour() instead getRealHours($labour->minutes_worked)

Comment: I think there may be a simpler way to do it, look at the update response.